# How to change the Start color of the Particle System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am just trying to simply change the start color of a particle system via script, and it's not working.

```
 private ParticleSystem trailPartical;   // The  particle system

 public Color StartColor
 {
      var main = trailPartical.main;
      main.startColor = value;
 }
```

This is not working at all, and I have also tried the depreciated version:

```
 trailParticle.startColor = value;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to use `StartColor` as a method, judging by the code inside the {}, even though you declared it as a variable.

Apart from this mistake, due to some changes in the ParticleSystem, you need to access the main module of the component:

```
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main;
main.startColor = Color.blue; // <- or whatever color you want to assign
```

inside a script attached to the game which also has the particle system component.

Comment: That worked, but any idea why I couldn't do this in a Setter method? I had to make a method specifically for this that takes in a Color as parameter.

Comment: @BenjaFriend The other answer provided by Programmer shows you exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you are trying to do. You want to simplify setting the color with just one function or property.

You will get this error with your current code:

> A get or set accessor expected.

That's because you did not implement the set accesstor.

That property should be like this:

```
private ParticleSystem trailPartical; 

public Color StartColor
{
    set
    {
        var main = trailPartical.main;
        main.startColor = value;
    }
}
```

then...

```
void Start()
{
    trailPartical = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    StartColor = Color.red;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody wondering how to set the gradient:

```
ParticleSystem.MainModule psMain = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main;
psMain.startColor = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient(Color.white, Color.red);
```